# Self Signed and Domain Created Certificates not being accepted by browsers?

Tags: tls

We have recently had some software installed that uses a web-based panel as well as an application. We have been using the application software, but we have been asked to implement the web-based panel, which is fine. It seemed fairly simple as most of it was one using the software itself to create the site and all we had to site assign a certificate to it.

We assigned the certificate to it in the binding section of IIS but it doesn't trust it.

We have tried a self-signed certificate as well as a domain certificate but neither of them seem to work.

Once created we have attempted to import them into chrome but it puts them in "Other people" rather then the trusted root tab. We tried to force it into the trusted root tab and it gives an import successful but doesn't actually do anything.

I'm fairly new to SSL and IIS so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also forgot to mention we had underscores in it and also had ESET Installed we thought both of these were making difference but apparently not.

Comment: Try running the server test at https://www.ssllabs.com/, and this will likely show you what the problem is with your SSL config.